# Get Identity of multiple insertion in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

Hi
Im going to insert 10 rows in a time using one TSQL which is available in SQL server 2008.
I want the IDENTITY of inserted rows. I think the below solution would work but Im not sure if some other insertion happens while im running the previous insertion would affect the result

`INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (1,2), (3,4), (4,5), ....

DECLARE @LastID INT = @@IDENTITY 

SELECT TOP(10) ID FROM tableA WHERE ID<=@LastID ORDER BY ID DESC`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) - it can either return output to the application, or into a table variable for further work.

E.g. your query would be:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
OUTPUT inserted.ID
VALUES (1,2), (3,4), (4,5), ...
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause:

```
DECLARE @tablevar table (ID int);

INSERT INTO tableA 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @tablevar 
VALUES (1,2), (3,4), (4,5), ....
```

Comment: Wonderful answer, exactly what i need, but is it possible to avoid temp table ?

Comment: @Ehsan - just omit the `INTO @MyTableVar` portion.

Comment: @Ehsan: can I suggest you accept Damien's answer.